# A closed form for $\int_0^\pi \lvert \sin(m t) \cos(n t) \rvert \, \mathrm{d} t$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859232/evaluate-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0x-max-sin-t-sint-sqrt2-dt) nice question I have been trying to compute the function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ defined by

> $$f(\alpha) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int \limits_0^x \lvert\sin(\alpha s) \cos(s)\rvert \, \mathrm{d} s \, .$$

Note that $f(\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

In the answers to the original question the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) is used to show that $f(3 - 2 \sqrt{2}) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}$ holds. This argument can be extended to every irrational number, so we have $f(\alpha) = \frac{4}{\pi^2} \approx 0.405285$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \mathbb{Q}^+$ .

For rational arguments we can take $m , n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n) =1$ . The change of variables $s = n t$ yields
$$ f \left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int \limits_0^x \lvert\sin(m t) \cos(n t)\rvert \, \mathrm{d} t \, .$$
The integrand is periodic with period $\pi$, so
$$ f \left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \left[\bigg\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \bigg\rfloor \int \limits_0^\pi \lvert\sin(m t) \cos(n t)\rvert \, \mathrm{d} t + \mathcal{O} (1)\right] = \frac{1}{\pi} \int \limits_0^\pi \lvert\sin(m t) \cos(n t)\rvert \, \mathrm{d} t\, .$$

Now the idea is to split the interval of integration into subintervals on which the sign of the product is constant and then use
$$ \sin(m t) \cos(n t) = \frac{\sin[(m+n)t] + \sin[(m-n)t]}{2}$$
to find the integrals. The result is basically given by a finite sum of cosines evaluated at the zeroes of the integrand.

The first few results are
\begin{align}
f(1) &= \frac{1}{\pi} \approx 0.318301 \, , \\ 
f(2) &= \frac{4}{3 \pi} \approx 0.424413 \, , \\
f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{2(2\sqrt{2}-1)}{3\pi} \approx 0.388004 \, .
\end{align}
Interestingly, most of the other values (especially those with large $m$ and $n$) seem to be very close to $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ .

This method can be used (at least in principle) to compute $f$ at every rational argument, but it becomes increasingly complicated for larger values of $m$ and $n$ . Maybe I am overlooking a simple trick, maybe there is a better method. My question is:

> How can we find a general expression for $f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$ with arbitrary coprime $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

---

**Edit 1 July 2020**

Thanks to Zacky's bounty and River Li's and asgeige's nice answers we have some closed-form results for special cases and a promising (but still somewhat complicated) conjecture for the general case. Using similar methods, I have also found
$$ f(m) = \frac{2}{\pi (m^2-1)} \left[m \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2m} 1_{2\mathbb{N}}(m)\right) - 1_{2 \mathbb{N}-1}(m)\right]$$
for $m \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ ($1_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$), which implies $\lim_{m \to \infty} f(m) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}$. While a simple expression for general values of $m,n$ seems unlikely, it may be possible to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f \left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} f \left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}$ do indeed hold for fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, respectively.

---

**Edit 11 January 2021**

Thanks to River Li's second answer we now have a proof of the conjectured limits. We can even use partial fractions and the pole expansions of $\csc$ and $\cot$ to simplify the remaining series and obtain the following general result (valid for $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ coprime and not both equal to $1$):
$$ f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{g_m\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\right) - g_m \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{m^2-n^2} \, , \, g_m = \begin{cases} x \mapsto \frac{\csc(x)}{x} &, \, m \in 2 \mathbb{N} - 1 \\ x \mapsto \frac{\cot(x)}{x} &, \, m \in 2 \mathbb{N}\end{cases} \, . $$

Comment: Finding a closed form seems a bit unlikely, of course I will be happy to be proven wrong, but I would also gladly give the bounty to an answer that shows significant progress such as finding a closed form when $n$ or $m$ is fixed (e.g. $n=1$ and $m\in \mathbb N$), or for proving "OP's conjecture" that for large $m$ and $n$ the result tends indeed to $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$, or other stuff.

Comment: Quick comment: have you already tried to obtain a Fourier series of $sgn(\cos(nt))sgn(\sin(mt))$? Perhaps the convolution theorem would be useful, since the coefficients for those square waves are well known.

Comment: The OP's final result is very nice! I have not thought it has a simple closed form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $m\ge 1, n\ge 1$, $m\ne n$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(m, n) = 1$.

By the identity
$$\left|\sin x\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)}\cos(2k x),$$
we have
$$|\sin mt | = \frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4i^2-1)}\cos(2i mt)$$
and
$$|\cos nt| = |\sin (\pi/2 - nt)|
 = \frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4j^2-1)}(-1)^j \cos(2jnt).$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
|\sin (mt) \cos (nt)| &= \frac{4}{\pi^2}
- \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4i^2-1)}\cos(2i mt)\\
&\quad - \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4j^2-1)}(-1)^j \cos(2jnt)\\
&\quad + \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{16(-1)^j}{\pi^2(4i^2-1)(4j^2-1)}\cos(2i mt)\cos(2jnt).
\end{align}
Note that
$$\int_0^\pi \cos(2i mt)\cos(2jnt) \mathrm{d} t = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                                                           0 & im - jn \ne 0 \\[4pt]
                                                           \frac{\pi}{2} & im - jn = 0.
                                                         \end{array}
\right.$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin (mt) \cos (nt)| \mathrm{d} t
&= \frac{4}{\pi^2} + \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{8(-1)^j}{\pi^2 (4i^2-1)(4j^2-1)}\delta(i m - jn)\\
&= \frac{4}{\pi^2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{8(-1)^{km}}{\pi^2 (4k^2n^2-1)(4k^2m^2-1)}\\
&= \frac{4}{\pi^2} + \frac{1}{m^2n^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{8(-1)^{km}}{\pi^2 (4k^2-1/n^2)(4k^2-1/m^2)}.
\end{align}
Note that
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{8(-1)^{km}}{\pi^2 (4k^2-1/n^2)(4k^2-1/m^2)}
\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{8}{\pi^2 (4k^2-1)(4k^2-1)} = \frac{\pi^2 - 8}{2\pi^2}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\lim_{\max(m, n) \to \infty} \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin (mt) \cos (nt)| \mathrm{d} t = \frac{4}{\pi^2}.$$

Answer (score 11):

**Case** $m = 1$

By using Maple, we have
\begin{align}
f(\tfrac{1}{n}) &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin t \cos (nt)| \mathrm{d} t\\
&= \frac{2(n - \sin \tfrac{\pi}{2n})}{(n^2-1)\pi \sin \tfrac{\pi}{2n}}.
\end{align}
We have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(\tfrac{1}{n}) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}.$$

**Case** $m=2$, and $n$ odd

By using Maple, we have
\begin{align}
f(\tfrac{2}{n}) &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin 2t \cos (nt)| \mathrm{d} t\\
&= \frac{2(n \cos \frac{\pi}{2n}-2\sin \frac{\pi}{2n} )}{(n^2-4)\pi \sin \frac{\pi}{2n}}.
\end{align}
We have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(\tfrac{2}{n}) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}.$$

**General Case** $m \ne n$

Based on the results for $m=1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots$ by Maple, after simplification and observation, I $\color{blue}{\textrm{GUESS}}$ that, for $m, n \ge 1$ and $m\ne n$, 
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi |\sin (mt) \cos (nt)| \mathrm{d} t \\
=\ & \frac{2n}{n^2-m^2}
\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}\rfloor - 1} 
\left|\sin \frac{m\pi (1 + 4s)}{2n}\right|
+ \sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \rfloor - 1}
\left|\sin \frac{m\pi (3 + 4s)}{2n}\right|\right)\\
&\quad - \frac{2m}{n^2-m^2}\sum_{s=0}^{m-1} \left|\cos \frac{s\pi n}{m}\right|
\end{align}
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Remarks: 1. I have done numerical experiments $1\le m, n \le 10$ and more.

2. Rigorous and step-by-step proofs are expected.
3. Further simplification may be possible.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Integrand  I am trying to calculate $m=2$ and more. I believe all these are too long for a comment.

Comment: i proved the first two of your results.

Comment: @asgeige Very nice. $m=1$ is easy even by hand. The general case may be not easy.

Answer (score 8):

**Notation**

$$f_{m,n}(x)=\sin(mx)\cos(nx)\\
 \pi I_{m,n}=\int_0^{\pi}dx |f_{m,n}(x)|\\
\mathcal{I}_{m,n,k}=\int_{\frac{\pi (2k-1)}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi (2k+1)}{2n}}f_{m,n}(x)dx\\ 
\mathcal{I}_{m,n,0}=\int_0^{\pi/(2n)}f_{m,n}(x)dx\\
 \mathcal{I}_{m,n,n}=\int^{\pi}_{\pi-\pi/(2n)}f_{m,n}(x)dx
$$

---

**Lemma 1:**

$$
\int dt \cos(nt)\sin(mt)=\frac{1}{n^2-m^2}(m\sin(nt)\sin(mt)+n\cos(nt)\cos(mt))
$$

**Proof**: direct differentation

---

**Partial results I: $m=1$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.**

Define
$$
I_{1,n}=I_{n}\\
f_{1,n}(x)=f_{n}(x)\\
\mathcal{I_{k,n}}=\mathcal{I_{1,k,n}}
$$
Now,we can split the integral as follows:
$$
\pi I_n= \mathcal{I}_{n,0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \mathcal{I}_{n,k}+(-1)^n\mathcal{I}_{n,n}\quad(\star)
$$

By Lemma 1, we have by taking into account that $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ that
$$
\mathcal{I}_{n,k}=(-1)^k\sin(k \pi/2n)\frac{2n \cos(\pi/2n)}{n^2-1}\\
\mathcal{I}_{n,0}=\frac{-1+n \sin(\pi/2n)}{n^2-1}\\
\mathcal{I}_{n,n}=(-1)^n\mathcal{I}_{n,0}
$$

Using $\Im(e^{ix})=\sin(x)$ together with the finite geometric series we easily obtain:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \mathcal{I}_{n,k}=\cot(\pi/2n)\frac{2n \cos(\pi/2n)}{n^2-1}
$$

so from $(\star)$ we have

> $$
> \pi I_n=
> \frac{2}{n^2-1}\left(\frac{n}{\sin(\pi/2n)}-1\right)
> $$

The limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ is now easily obtained:

$$
I_{\infty}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}
$$
as conjectured.

---

**Partial results II: $m=2$, $n \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$.**

Since $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(nx)$ have both a nice symmetry point (both change sign simultaniously in the same direction) at $x=\frac{\pi}2$
we can split the integral in this case as follows:

$$
\pi I_{2,n}= 2(\mathcal{I}_{2,n,0}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (-1)^k \mathcal{I}_{2,n,k})\quad(\star \star)
$$

we, again by Lemma 1, have:

$$
\mathcal{I}_{2,n,k}=(-1)^k\sin(2 k \pi/n)\frac{2n \cos(\pi/n)}{n^2-4}\\
\mathcal{I}_{2,n,0}=\frac{-2+n \sin(\pi/n)}{n^2-4}\\
$$

Using once again $\Im(e^{ix})=\sin(x)$ together with the finite geometric series we easily obtain:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (-1)^k \mathcal{I}_{2,n,k}=\frac{\cot(\pi/2n)}{2}\frac{2n \cos(\pi/n)}{n^2-4}
$$

merging everything in $(\star \star)$ we get (after some trig-manipulations)

> $$
> \pi I_{2,n}=
> \frac{2}{n^2-4}\left(n\cot(\pi/2n)-2\right)
> $$

Taking the limit of $n\rightarrow\infty$ we get, since $\cot(y)\sim_{0_+} 1/y$

$$
I_{2,\infty}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}
$$
as expected.

---

More tomorrow